# Putting opaque legend background over gridlines in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, opacity

Consider the code:

```
  plot1 = ContourPlot[{x y == 2, x y == 6}, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, 
            ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Black]
  
  Legended[Show[plot1], Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"x * y  =  2", "x * y  =  6"}, 
         LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> Opacity[0.7, White]] &)], {.25, .75}]]
```

In the output, the opacity of the background of the legend does not seem to be working over the gridline:

[image: Using ContourPlot]

Whereas, the expected output is:

[image: Using Plot]

The second one has been generated using Plot function instead of ContourPlot.

(This is obviously an overly simplified example. For my original purpose, I need to use ContourPlot, and make the legend background opaque over the gridlines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> False}`:

```
ContourPlot[{x y == 2, x y == 6}
 , {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}
 , ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , GridLinesStyle -> Black
 , Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> False}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue}
    , {"x * y  =  2", "x * y  =  6"}
    , LegendFunction -> (Framed[#
        , Background -> Opacity[0.7, White]] &)]
   , {.25, .75}
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Just I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

- It seems that the `GridLines` in `ContourPlot` delay drawing.
- Here is a working around. Using `Mesh` to draw gridlines.

```
plot1 = ContourPlot[x y - 2, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red, Mesh -> {5, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &},
    Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None];
plot2 = ContourPlot[x y - 6, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, 
  ContourStyle -> Blue, Mesh -> {5, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &},
   Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None];
Legended[
 Show[plot1, plot2], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"x * y  =  2", "x * y  =  6"}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
       Background -> Opacity[0.7, White]] &)], {.25, .75}]]
```

[image]